# What do you call a person who is always keen to learn new things?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a person who is always ready and keen to learn new things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use:

**inquisitive**
or
**motivated**

Comment: I think inquisitive is a good choice, but motivated is not. I can be motivated to do a lot of things unrelated to learning, by circumstances that are unrelated to my insatiable desire to learn.

Comment: "Inquisitive" is the word which suits the purpose of the question. So accepted this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The closest word I can think of would be **receptive** or **eager**. However, for preciseness, you should say **eager to learn new things**.

Comment: you **still** need to add 'to learn new things'. That said, those words, without any supportive text, don't mean 'someone keen to learn'.

Comment: Yes, because there's really not one single word that specifically means always keen and ready to learn new things. However, receptive is ready to learn or accepting, and eager is keen to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You could call them "curious".

Comment: I think an example sentence would help. If I say "he was a curious boy" it's ambiguous whether I mean he was interested in knowing things, or he was not a normal child.

Comment: Personally, I think curious is probably the best word suggested, but this answer leaves something to be desired. An example sentence would be good, perhaps a definition from a linked dictionary. More details, basically. This would almost be better as a comment on another answer, or edited into one.

Comment: No other gave examples or definition either.
I feel there's something wrong with this platform, as I'm forced to append thirty dots just to thank or as in this case to answer a dedicatedly tagged "single-word" question, which results in my answer, for the content of which I am responsible, being edited by someone who apparently has nothing better to do than making ridiculous, little changes, keeping a ridiculous form for no reason. "My" answer doesn't convey any more content now than before with the dots.

Comment: @rednaZ The editor's goal was probably not to put words in your mouth  while making your answer a complete sentence. He did you a favor, because single word answers are likely to be deleted.  You can always roll it back if you object to it. You might want to take a tour around the help center to get a better understanding of how stack exchange sites work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a noun, the best would be probably be **polymath**, or at least one seeking to become one.

**Polymath**
a person of wide-ranging knowledge or learning

Comment: The second paragraph appears to be a quote; if that's the case, please [edit] to include the source you got it from.

Answer (score 0):

You may also call them a 'sophopile' - lover of knowledge.

Comment: Can you edit to provide a link to a source which justifies this?